# How to use Cloudformation to attach lambda function to existing API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying automate attaching a lambda function to an already existing Api Gateway(that was not deployed in a stack). It looks like the AWS::ApiGateway::Method is the best way of going about doing this, but I can seem to figure out how to get the specific Api Gateway RestApiId and ResourceId. How can I go about "fetching" that information? Is there a cloudformation way or do I need to use some type of lambda function?

Thanks for helping me with frustrating problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way to do this would be using a CFN parameter. I've put a small example of how this can be done below. The example uses a SAM serverless lambda and an HTTP API (API gateway v2), but the solution for a REST API (API gateway v1) would be very similar.

```
Parameters:
  HttpApi:
    Type: String

Resources:
  SourceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      [...]
      Events:
        GetEndpoint:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: /endpoint
            Method: GET
            ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
```

More information about cloudformation parameters can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).
More information about the serverless function (in case you're not familiar with AWS SAM) can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the parameters section to help cut back on hardcoding the values

Comment: When I try this I keep getting this: `Error: [InvalidResourceException('MyFunction', "Event with id [ApiEvent] is invalid. ApiId must be a valid reference to an 'AWS::Serverless::HttpApi' resource in same template.")]`

Comment: @peoplespete we can't help you without a full cfn template. Maybe open a mew question?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go about "fetching" that information?

There is **no such functionality** as "fetching" in CFN. You have to provide everything manually as input parameters or hard-code the values that you want. Alternatively, you have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to get that info for you. The custom resource would use a **lambda function** that you need to write yourself.

Comment: Thanks for helping me get out of that mental loop I was stuck in. I realized I was trying to be too slick